# Numpy: creating an empty array results in memory error?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, numpy

I need to store a ton of information in a numpy array.  It needs to be of the following shape:

```
facefeature1s = np.empty([2000,64,64,64,32])
```

When I run this, i get a memory error.  What can I do about this?

Error is:

```
    MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-271-2c56a37b4a7c> in <module>()
----> 1 facefeature1s = np.empty([2000,64,64,64,32])
```

Comment: Either buy 134 GB of RAM or make a smaller array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Jaime says in the comments, your array is too big. IF you really need such a huge array, you can use [`numpy.memmap()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to work on the array using the hard drive:

```
a = np.memmap('filename.myarray', dtype=np.float64, mode='w+',
              shape=(2000, 64, 64, 64, 32))
```

The next time you open the array, use `mode='r'`, or `mode='r+'`.

Comment: Weird, I have hundreds of Gigs left but it says the following error:
[Errno 28] No space left on device